# What is the meaning of this information in my broker account?

Tags: stocks

> APPLE INC CASH DIV ON 5700 SHS REC 02/09/15 PAY 02/12/15 NON-RES TAX
>   WITHHELD $267.90000

Thanks,

Comment: In what country?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that you received a dividend from Apple with a Record date of Feb. 2nd 2015, a Payment Date of Feb. 12 2015, and Non-Resident Tax withheld of $267.90.

Apple paid a $0.47 per share cash dividend, so for the 5700 shares you hold you would have received a dividend amount of $2679 ($0.47 x 5700) with 10% ($267.90) withheld as above, for a net dividend of $2411.10 which you should have received.